# Unusual behaviour of text field .Clear text field data on click event of button 

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

When user click on button , I want to clear text field. How can i do this?

My code is as follows =>

```
textFieldName.text = nil;
textViewAddress.text = nil;
```

But this code is not clearing the text field, but it clears the textView. Also when i use backspace button from keyboard of iphone it is not clearing textfield. If i write something in textfield it starts writing on top of existing characters.

Please help me friends. Thanks

Comment: Can you post more code? Your whole UIViewController with these text fields?

Comment: Problem might be there in some other place. Bcz `textField.text = nil;` should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would be sufficient

```
textFieldName.text = @"";
textViewAddress.text = @"";
```

Comment: Nope, nil should done this too. There must be something else, which causes this problem.

Comment: @Cheifly Izzy: 7KV7 is right. It is required that you set it to `@""` and not `nil`.

Comment: @appDev: also did you check if your outlets are properly connected to your textfields?

Comment: My outlets are connected properly. I can write in textfield first time without any problem.